# TS1109: Expression expected and TS1005: ':' expected error in Angular

Tags: angular

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Getting error at below line,

```
this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas?.nativeElement,{
```

At the dot after the question mark, (TS1109: Expression expected)

And at comma after nativeElement, (TS1005: ':' expected)

```
export class GraphViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('lineCanvas', {static: false}) lineCanvas: ElementRef | undefined;
    lineChart: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.lineChartMethod();
    }


lineChartMethod() {        
            this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas?.nativeElement,{
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [
                    'January',
```

Code reference,
https://edupala.com/how-to-use-angular-chartjs/#Adding_Angular_chartjs_to_our_application

Comment: These are just TypeScript warnings, you should be able to safely ignore them

Comment: What about an exclamation mark instead ?
And I guess putting `if (this.lineCanvas)` above clear the warning no ?

Answer (score 0):

check if lineCanvas and its nativeElement exist before you try to use them

```
lineChartMethod() {
    if (this.lineCanvas && this.lineCanvas.nativeElement) {
        this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [
                    'January',
                    // ... other months
                ],
                // ... rest of your chart configuration
            }
        });
    }
}
```